# Why is docker-compose creating volume in random path instead of the path I specified in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, sonatype, nexus3

I am trying to store nexus data in persistent volume. To do that I am using this compose yaml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
       - ./nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - devops
    extra_hosts:
      - "my-proxy:my-proxy-address"
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  devops:
    name: devops
    driver: bridge
```

Before running `docker-compose up` I have created the `nexus-data` folder and gave required permissions to the `uid/guid 200` as suggested here:

https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3/blob/master/README.md#persistent-data.

```
root@master-node:~/docker# ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan  8 13:37 ./
drwx------ 22 root root 4096 Jan  8 13:40 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  319 Jan  8 13:36 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2  200  200 4096 Jan  8 13:37 nexus-data/
```

And here docker's volumes list before running compose file (it's empty):

```
root@master-node:~/docker# docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
```

After `docker-compose up` command, docker created the volume as shown below:

```
root@master-node:~/docker# docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               7b7b6517e5ed0e286a8fc7caef756141b5bbdb6e074ef93a657850da3dd78b2b
root@master-node:~/docker# docker volume inspect  7b7b6517e5ed0e286a8fc7caef756141b5bbdb6e074ef93a657850da3dd78b2b 
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-01-08T13:42:34+03:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/7b7b6517e5ed0e286a8fc7caef756141b5bbdb6e074ef93a657850da3dd78b2b/_data",
        "Name": "7b7b6517e5ed0e286a8fc7caef756141b5bbdb6e074ef93a657850da3dd78b2b",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
root@master-node:~/docker# ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/7b7b6517e5ed0e286a8fc7caef756141b5bbdb6e074ef93a657850da3dd78b2b/_data
admin.password  cache  db  elasticsearch  etc  generated-bundles  instances  javaprefs  karaf.pid  keystores  lock  log  orient  port  restore-from-backup  tmp
```

but the folder I specified in compose file (`nexus-data`) is still empty:

```
root@master-node:~/docker# ls nexus-data/
root@master-node:~/docker#
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Why is`nexus-data` empty and docker creating volume in another path?

Comment: There's a space in the container-side path in your `volumes:` directive; is that correct?

Comment: Declare you volume like this `- ./nexus-data:/nexus-data`.

Comment: On official docs, there are using plain docker command `docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3`. The volume part is `-v nexus-data:/nexus-data` but not `sonatype/nexus3` which is the image's name.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, changing path to ./nexus-data:/nexus-data solved my problem. If you consider to write as an answer your comments I can accept it. @leopal

Comment: I used the guide from this blog post: https://medium.com/@ahmed24khaled/building-e2e-devops-pipeline-a0f7804390f7 
 and this repo: https://github.com/ahmed24khaled/DevOps-app/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml but it turns out that the guide has some problems. Updating path as ./nexus-data:/nexus-data solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a host volume, aka bind mount (which doesn't show in `docker volume ls` since it's not a named volume)B from `./nexus-data` on the host to `/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3` inside the container. This looks like a copy and paste error from a `docker run` command since you are adding the image name to the path being mounted inside the container. You should be able to exec into the container and see your files with:

```
docker exec ... ls "/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3"
```

You should remove the image name from the volume path to mount the typical location inside the container:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
       - ./nexus-data:/nexus-data
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - devops
    extra_hosts:
      - "my-proxy:my-proxy-address"
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  devops:
    name: devops
    driver: bridge
```

The volume you did see was an anonymous volume. This would be from the image itself defining a volume that you did not include in your container spec. Inspecting the container using that volume would show where it's mounted, most likely at `/nexus-data`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems the guide I have used had some problems. Updating the path solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

You defined a volume instead of a bind mount, which is what you want. Read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) about it.

Basically, your configuration makes docker create a `volume`, which maps to a randomly created directory somewhere under `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

If you want a specific directory that you control, you have to create a `bind`. That's the reason you don't have data on your chosen directory, as docker ignores it because it is not useful for a `volume`.

For it to work, set it like:

```yml
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./nexus-data
        target: /nexus-data
```

as explained in the compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes). (Also removed the image name from that configuration)

Comment: I downvote'd because OP's questions are "... what am I doing wrong here? Why is the nexus-data is empty and docker creating volume in another path?" none of which have been addressed in your answer.

Comment: I used the guide from this blog post: https://medium.com/@ahmed24khaled/building-e2e-devops-pipeline-a0f7804390f7 
 and this repo: https://github.com/ahmed24khaled/DevOps-app/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml but it turns out that the guide has some problems. Updating path as ./nexus-data:/nexus-data solved my problem.

Comment: @samthegolden points for the lastest edit. Note: the [v3 short syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) `./path:/path` is of type `bind` (is equivalent to the explicit [long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3)).

Answer (score 1):

The below `docker-compose.yaml` works as expected:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
       - ./nexus-data:/nexus-data
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - devops
    extra_hosts:
      - "my-proxy:my-proxy-address"
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  devops:
    name: devops
    driver: bridge
```

The trailing `sonatype/nexus3` in your original `docker-compose.yaml` spec:

```
    ...
    volumes:
       - ./nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
    ...
```

... throws `docker` off - the randomly named volume is created given the `VOLUME` instruction in the `sonatype/nexus3` `Dockerfile` and is mounted to the running container hence why the intended locally mounted directory is empty.

Comment: @whoever_that_downvoted any reason as to why? Is nonconstructive imho to downvote "just because".

Comment: It wasn't me. I have upvoted your answer. Thank you.